# Converting time series into vector

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for an approach to convert a time series data into vectors. An example of what I am trying to achieve is given below.

```
Data x = x1,x2,x3,..x100
Required vectors = V1(x1,x2,x3),V2(x2,x3,x4), V3(x3,x4,x5).. v98(x98,x99,x100)
```

I could convert the complete time series into Vector. But I do not know how I could achieve the above result.

Thanks for all leads.

I am trying this in R.

Comment: Please `dput()` your data. Read [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `embed(x,98)`.

(Entering extra characters just to post this.)