# SAX method: cut time series into subsequences then calculate distances (Python)

Tags: python, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I am trying to apply SAX (Symbolic Aggregation Approximation) method to detect outliers on my time series data. Basically I need to cut the whole series into equal length sub-series, then calculate the distances between each of them. Then the top-K sub-series are marked as abnormal.

Tried a few packages:

- `pyts` - not sure how to cut the series in the first place
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935000/converting-time-series-into-vector) is relatable - is there any better solution in python?
- `tslearn.metrics.dtw_path_from_metric` - looks like it's calculating distances between two series, but I am missing the first "cutting" part.
- Also I was thinking if a matrix would work (with each sub-series as row and column, then distances are laid out on the diagnosis)

The outcome is 1) cut the series by week; 2) calculate the distances between each subseries; 3) rand them, with the top-k longest-distance ones. I know it's probably a lot to ask, but any suggestion will be really appreciated!

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import bumpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
base = datetime.datetime.today()
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='6/1/2020', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['date'])
df['sales'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(dates)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer to 1) cut the series by week

Although you could probably just get away with using `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W'))` perhaps more useful would be to populate to dataframe with the week_number and week_date attributes.

```
week = 1
weekly_data = []
week_data = []
for data in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W')):
    week_date = data[0]
    week_dates = list(data[1]['date'])
    week_sales = list(data[1]['sales'])
    week_data_list = list(zip(week_dates, week_sales))
    for i in week_data_list:
        week_data.append([week, week_date, i[0], i[1]])
    weekly_data.append(week_data)
    week += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(week_data, columns=['week_number', 'week_date', 'date', 'sales'])
df
```

This produces a dataframe of shape:

```
    week_number week_date   date    sales
0   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-01  57
1   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-02  64
2   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-03  51
3   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-04  77
4   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-05  69
... ... ... ... ...
148 22  2020-05-31  2020-05-28  34
149 22  2020-05-31  2020-05-29  51
150 22  2020-05-31  2020-05-30  66
151 22  2020-05-31  2020-05-31  77
152 23  2020-06-07  2020-06-01  31
153 rows × 4 columns
```

You can simply select or iteration on the dimension you want e.g.

```
df.loc[weeks_df['week_number'] == 1]

    week_number week_date   date    sales
0   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-01  57
1   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-02  64
2   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-03  51
3   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-04  77
4   1   2020-01-05  2020-01-05  69
```

Do note that this will not give you equal length subseries for each week because your data example does not allow for that, the first week having only 5 values and week 23 having only 1.

Good luck with 2) and 3)